# stackblitz component search in component tree for react dev tools

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to lean react by solving a problem in react. Providing the react code challenge below.
I am trying to debug the drop down functionality using react dev tools.
In the youtube video I am seeing the stateDropDown but in stackblitz I am not seeing.
I search in stackblitz component tree but still no luck

I googled but still no luck, not sure how to solve it. Providing my code below and stackblitz. Can you guys help me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2zEAXLQbF4&t=794s

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ngl4yu?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2Fcomponents%2FstateDropdown.css,src%2Fcomponents%2FStateDropdown.tsx,src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FStates.tsx&title=React%20Starter

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './stateDropdown.css';
import { states } from './States';
export function StateDropdown() {
  const [isDropDownDisplayed, setIsDropdowndisplayed] = useState(false);
  const [selectedStates, setSelectedStates] = useState<Record<string, boolean>>(
    states.reduce((obj, state) => ({ ...obj, [state.abbreviation]: false }), {})
  );
  return (
    <fieldset className="state-dropdown">
      <button
        className=""
        onClick={() => setIsDropdowndisplayed((prevState) => !prevState)}
      >
        -- Select your states --
      </button>
      {isDropDownDisplayed && (
        <div className="panel">
          {states.map((state) => (
            <fieldset key={state.abbreviation}>
              <input id={`input-${state.abbreviation}`} type="checkbox" />
              <label htmlFor={`input-${state.abbreviation}`}>
                {state.name}
              </label>
            </fieldset>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </fieldset>
  );
}
```

[image]

[image]